# Consulta tomar coordenadas de región en google maps

Tags: google-maps

Quiero tomar las coordenadas de toda una región en `google maps`, por ejemplo ésta:

https://www.google.com.pe/maps/place/R%C3%ADmac/@-12.0211132,-77.0504372,14z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x9105cf41e6ed1dad:0xb30871711a844983!8m2!3d-12.0271206!4d-77.0362378

Tomarlas de 1 en 1 es mucho trabajo, ¿Álguien sabe cómo puedo tomarlas?

Comment: Pero, ¿de qué quieres buscar las coordenadas?, ¿de las calles?, ¿de los bordes del mapa que se muestra en pantalla?,... En el mapa que enlazas se ven muchas cosas pero no me queda claro a qué te refieres cuando dices que 'tomarlas una a una es mucho trabajo'.

Comment: Hola ,parece que ahora ya no sale la región, cuando puse el link salia una region y no solo el punto de localizacion , osea todo rimac , una superficie no uniforme , si hago click puedo sacar la coordenada punto or punto pero es muy trabajoso.

Answer (score 7):

Según entiendo, necesitas información sobre los polígonos que forman las ciudades en un mapa. Esta información está disponible en distintas API. Una de las más simples es utilizar **Natural Earth Data**.

Primero debes realizar una búsqueda con alguna keyword que defina la ciudad (Barcelona en mi caso), obtener el id de este polígono y luego una segunda request donde obtienes las coordenadas del polígono.

```
$ curl http://unlock.edina.ac.uk/ws/search?name=barcelona&gazetteer=naturalearth&format=json

{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "14121712",
      "bbox": [
        2.311441421508789,
        41.21774673461914,
        1.597888708114624,
        41.966922760009766
      ],
      "properties": {
        ...
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "14131209",
      "bbox": [
        -64.65343475341797,
        10.069979667663574,
        -64.74640655517578,
        10.16857624053955
      ],
      "properties": {
       ...
      }
    }
  ],
  "totalResults": "2"
}
```

y luego con el id, consultar el polígono respectivo:

```
$ curl http://unlock.edina.ac.uk/ws/footprintLookup?format=json&identifier= 14121712

{
  "type": "FootprintCollection",
  "footprints": [
    {
      "type": "Footprint",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
         ...
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "id": "14121712",
        "custodian": "Natural Earth"
      }
    }
  ],
  "totalResults": "1"
}
```

**Actualización**

Buscando mas información, llegue a la siguiente API:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&address=rimac
{
  "results": [
    {
      "address_components": [
        {
          "long_name": "Rimac",
          "short_name": "Rimac",
          "types": [
            "locality",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Lima Province",
          "short_name": "Lima Province",
          "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_2",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Lima Region",
          "short_name": "Lima Region",
          "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_1",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Peru",
          "short_name": "PE",
          "types": [
            "country",
            "political"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "formatted_address": "Rimac, Peru",
      "geometry": {
        "bounds": {
          "northeast": {
            "lat": -11.9983532,
            "lng": -77.0131999
          },
          "southwest": {
            "lat": -12.0440422,
            "lng": -77.052827
          }
        },
        "location": {
          "lat": -12.0271206,
          "lng": -77.0362378
        },
        "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport": {
          "northeast": {
            "lat": -11.9983532,
            "lng": -77.0131999
          },
          "southwest": {
            "lat": -12.0440422,
            "lng": -77.052827
          }
        }
      },
      "place_id": "ChIJrR3t5kHPBZERg0mEGnFxCLM",
      "types": [
        "locality",
        "political"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": "OK"
}
```

donde puedes poner una ciudad/localidad por nombre y te entregas los borders (boundaries) aproximados de esta.

Otra opción que encontré y no he probado es el siguiente repo de github [pgkelley4/city-boundaries-google-maps](https://github.com/pgkelley4/city-boundaries-google-maps).

**2ª Actualización**

encontré esto http://www.gadm.org/country que te puede servir aún más. Desde acá puedes bajar archivos con las coordenadas de los límites para distintos países y sus ciudades.

Primero debes bajar el KMZ y descomprimirlo (es un zip con extensión KMZ). Una vez extraído, tendrás un archivo KML con la información.

Bajé el de Perú y encontré lo que creo que necesitas:

```
<Placemark>
<name>Rimac</name>
<description><![CDATA[Distrito]]></description>
<styleUrl>#1263</styleUrl>
<visibility>1</visibility>
<MultiGeometry>
<Polygon>
<outerBoundaryIs>
<LinearRing>
<coordinates>
-77.0527191162109,-12.0110912322997
-77.050422668457,-12.0107746124268
-77.0494842529297,-12.0128049850464
-77.0483322143555,-12.0141773223876
-77.0475540161132,-12.0145559310913
-77.0462265014648,-12.0143136978149
-77.0451889038086,-12.0133800506591
-77.0447921752929,-12.0115766525269
-77.0438461303711,-12.0099821090698
-77.0367202758789,-12.0033292770385
-77.0323486328125,-12.0000171661377
-77.031135559082,-11.9979181289672
-77.0305709838867,-11.9962520599364
-77.0294876098633,-11.9970731735229
-77.0291061401367,-11.9976263046265
-77.0280838012695,-12.0033378601074
-77.0254898071289,-12.0059223175049
-77.025276184082,-12.0081043243408
-77.0232620239258,-12.0100164413452
-77.0227203369141,-12.0116910934448
-77.0207366943359,-12.0144710540771
-77.0198745727538,-12.0169095993042
-77.0195007324218,-12.0193881988525
-77.01953125,-12.0209417343139
-77.0204544067382,-12.0231685638428
-77.0213394165039,-12.0241098403931
-77.0221252441406,-12.025595664978
-77.0222549438476,-12.0267791748046
-77.0219726562499,-12.028037071228
-77.0212478637695,-12.0292272567749
[...]
```

espero haber ayudado

Comment: Hola amigo , exacto quiero sacar los poligonos , con la api que me diste , solo puedo sacar de ciertas zonas , por ejemplo quiero buscar el distrito de Rimac en lima , o Miraflores ,etc,etc y no las encuentra, pero algunas como Callao si las encuentra.

Comment: Hola, ahí ya la problemática de escapa de SOes ya que necesitas datos más que una forma de solucionar el problema. No conozco si google tendra expuesta una API, por lo que restaría que hagas un poco de investigación, ahora que tienes las palabras claves. De todas formas, creo que la respuesta soluciona tu problema, no?

Comment: @KevinAB actualicé la respuesta con información que encontré

Comment: @KevinAB podrías indicar si te fue útil la información?

Comment: @KevinAB, Pablo tiene razón, ya solucionó tu problema, la falta de información ya es otro tema completamente independiente.

Answer (score 5):

Desde Javascript puedes hacerlo con la api, con métodos como [getBounds()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) que devuelve un objeto [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds).

Creo que contiene toda la información que necesitas.

Answer (score -1):

ab, lamentablemente google no disponibiliza las fronteras de los mapas a través de la API, por lo que tendrías que recurrir a otro tipo de API.

Yo tuve este exacto problema en el pasado y solucionamos colocando un webcrawler sobre la herramienta de edición de google maps https://www.google.co.uk/mapmaker ya que en la época no encontramos ninguna empresa que suministrara o vendiera esa información con una calidad aceptable.